# Нужна ли запятая в последнем предложении перед "как"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, как

Если твоя цель – качество жизни и доступ к необходимым ресурсам, то зачем тратить все свои время и силы на монетизацию?

Вроде как нельзя по-другому. Можно. Просто ты пока не знаешь(,) как.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Просто ты пока не знаешь **как.***

Запятая в таких предложениях, как правило, не ставится. Но полного запрета нет, и даже возможна постановка тире.

> 4. Между главной и следующей за ней придаточной частью сложноподчиненного предложения запятая не ставится:
>    <...>
>    **3)** если придаточная часть состоит из одного союзного слова (относительного местоимения или наречия): *Я бы тоже желал знать **почему*** (Л. Т.)...
>    <...>
>    В условиях контекста возможна постановка запятой или тире и перед одиночным союзным словом: *Что же надо делать? Научите, **что*** — усиленное логическое выделение местоимения; *Одно время он что-то шептал, не могли понять — **что?*** (А. Т.) — постановка тире подчеркивает значение местоимения и оправдывается вопросительной интонацией.

Источник: [Запятая между главной и придаточной частями сложноподчиненного предложения](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=136) (справочник Розенталя).

P. S. Обратите внимание на фразу: ***все свои время и силы***. Лучше написать так: ***всё своё время и силы***. Или переставить слова: ***все свои силы и время***.

Comment: Александр, благодарю Вас!

Comment: @Леонид
Только на словах? Нужно еще нажать галочку и стрелочку.

Comment: @Sharon благодарю за подсказку, не знал. Поставил